# Collision physics error

Tags: collision-detection, 3d, scenekit

I am working on a game developed using Scenekit (iOS). I am facing some strange issues with collision physics.

I have added one **3D table (with a hole at its center)** to the scene. I am setting physics shape of this 3D model using following **code**:

```
SCNBox* tableBody = [SCNBox boxWithWidth:(5*golf.scale.x) height:(0.5*golf.scale.x) length:(9*golf.scale.x) chamferRadius:0];

table.geometry = tableBody; //table geometry

//physics shape scale
NSValue *shapeScale = [NSValue valueWithSCNVector3:SCNVector3Make(table.scale.x, table.scale.y, table.scale.z)];

//physics shape options
NSDictionary *shapeOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:shapeScale,SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey,SCNPhysicsShapeTypeConcavePolyhedron,SCNPhysicsShapeTypeKey, nil];

//physics body
table.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeStatic shape: [SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithNode:table  options:shapeOptions]];
```

I am adding **one 3D ball** on top of this table.

**Issue:**
The Ball collides with 3D table mesh triangles and changes directions

Image showing 3D table's physics shape:
[image]

**I have following questions:**

1. How can I stop collision of ball with these lines?
2. Are there any modification to the physics can be done? I want the hole to be part of the physics shape so that the ball can fall into the hole.

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue and was wondering if you found a solution. Thanks

Comment: This behavior is expected with mesh colliders. Simply collider shape to avoid this issue.